# Find duplicate key in key/value pair

Tags: php

I'm looking for some help finding the best solution to the following problem.

I have several php arrays in their own files looking like this:

```
<?php
$language_array = Array(

  'key'=>'value',
  'key'=>'value'
);
?>
```

What I'm trying to do is get a list of duplicate keys which exists in all the php array files.

I though about checking the first file and first key, and check this against all the other files. Then jump to the next key and continue.

So that I might end up with a list like this:

```
key = 'key' exist in all files
```

But I'm not sure about the performance, if I have to open each file x-times I have keys in it.

Any help much appreciated.

EDIT:

I solved it now using a temp array, and then comparing the current key with the temp, and if i have seen it already, add it to an array with just the duplicates.

Performance wise I'm not sure if this is the best solution, but using array_intersect was not working for me as I have no master array with all key=>values

Comment: Have you tried something? It's a good start with writing some code

Comment: Take a look at phps powerful array functions. Especially `array_intersect()` springs to mind here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php

Comment: I think his question isn't how to do but a performance question @arkascha

Comment: @niceman Well, reading all files once and building the intersection sounds much faster to me than reading the files again and again. But this will only work if the array sizes can fit into memory...

Comment: when you require/import a file , it's done, all the files contents are at your hand, you don't need to open , you just import/require them , you can use import/require once so you don't get errors

Comment: Thanks. I'm currently checking out an implementation using array_intersect. Initially I was also looking at including all array files.
But each next include would override the current array.
So also have to find a way to either add them to a new array, or do some other kind of variable name shifting.

Comment: Ok, so I played a little with array_intersect and array_intersect_key.
From what I can see in results, and what the PHP doc is telling me, these are not suitable for what I'm trying to achieve. Because both require a master file, including all keys, which I don't have.

Answer (score 0):

```
$aOne = Array(
    'key1'       =>'value1',
    'key2'       =>'value2',
    'key3'       =>'value3',
    'keyunique1' =>'uniquevalue1'
);
$aTwo = Array(
    'key2'       =>'value2',
    'key3'       =>'value3',
    'keyunique2' =>'uniquevalue2'
);
$aThree = Array(
    'key1'       =>'value1',
    'key2'       =>'value2',
    'key3'       =>'value3',
    'keyunique3' =>'uniquevalue3'
);
$aFour = Array(
    'key2'       =>'value2',
    'keyunique4' =>'uniquevalue4'
);

// Expected result key2 being the only one across all arrays.
$aUniques = array_intersect_key( $aOne, $aTwo, $aThree, $aFour );
```

Comment: I already mentioned in the above discussion, using array_intersect_key or any variant of array_intersect would not work in my case, as I don't have a master array with all key=>values.